# Euler 1, code doesnt work

Tags: c#

Euler problem:

If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

I tried to make the first problem from projecteuler.net. My code is as follows:

```
    int check = 3;
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            if (i == check)
            {
                result += i;
                check += 3;
            }
        }
        check = 5;
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            if (i == check)
            {
                result += i;
                check += 5;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

I know it can be optimized way better, but my code doesn't work and I don't know why. I tested it with 10 instead of 1000 and then it works. Does anybody see the mistake?

Edit: My code does work, but I get the wrong result. I get the right result when i use i < 10 in the for loop

Comment: You have to actually tell us what problem you are trying to solve. We are not going to go out to the Project Euler website just to read a problem description.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it now

Comment: And just for the fun of it, a short version would be: `Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.Range(1, 999).Where((n) => (n % 3==0 || n % 5==0)).Sum());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is:

You're checking numbers from 1 to 1000 once, which are multiple of 3. And, next you're also checking the numbers from 1 to 1000 next, which are multiple of 5.

But, you forgot the case that there can be several numbers which are multiples of both 3 and 5(e.g.,15,30,etc).

So, you should perform your operation in a single loop instead of checking it first by 3 and next by 5.

Do like :

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i=lower_limit;i<=upper_limit;i++){
    if(i%3==0 || i%5==0)
    sum = sum+i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As your code is written, it will add value 15 to `result` twice.
Once because 15 is a multiple of 3 and once again because 15 is a multiple of 5.

That seems wrong to me.  You only want to count 15 in your sum ***one*** time.

Answer (score 0):

If your number is a multiple of 3 **and** 5 (for example 15) you add it to `result` twice. Just use a single loop with the modulo operator:

```
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
        {
            result += i;
        }
    }
```